# Configuring .htaccess entry

Tags: .htaccess

Can anyone please Help me with this .htaccess entries

**htaccess entry for 301 Redirect Non-WWW to WWW URLs**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^!acethehimalaya.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.acethehimalaya.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Redirecting www.acethehimalaya.com/index.html to www.acethehimalaya.com**

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.html$ 

RewriteRule .* http://www.acethehimalaya.com/ [R=302,L]
```

Is all this entry valid as it  gives me problem and i m not able to login into my Back-End

Comment: I m not able to access my backend after this redirects. so is anything wrong with the entry ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

allow from all
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index.php\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://kursayin.am/ [R=301,L]
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

http://kursayin.am/index.php

it works for this site

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. And can u help me with the other entry of directing nonwww to www :)

Comment: I think if you should write  http://www acethehimalaya.com/ besides  http:// acethehimalaya.com/  and it'll work fine, I just tried it for kursayin.am and it changed to www.kursayin.am

Answer (score 0):

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index.html\ HTTP/

RewriteRule ^index.html$ http://acethehimalaya.com/ [R=301,L]

:) try this I use such code for my site

Comment: Its not being redirected at all :(

Comment: Thank you so much...i did a silly mistake with the code